# GE washer dryer combo doesn't wash, it just fills water then drain the water immediately

Tags: washing-machine

My washer dryer GE combination washer/dryer (model GUD24ESSMWW) doesn't wash or doesn't make a full cycle. When I choose a bulky items or normal wash cycle, it just starts filling the water without locking the lid. The light for the lock lid doesn't light up. It just fills water then drains it immediately. When I try the only drain and spin choice, it locks the lid and starts spinning.

Comment: what is the model, so we can help you looking for spare part

Comment: The model is model GUD24essmww